# Why does Ctrl key resize window in Unity desktop?

Tags: 12.04, unity, window, shortcut-keys

I have an almost out-of-the-box install of 12.04 Precise.  I am familiar with assigning and reassigning keyboard shortcuts, as I interact with my computer almost entirely through the keyboard.

I am new to the Unity desktop, and so this behavior is mysterious to me.  The keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> is ubiquitous in both the terminal and Emacs, so it's quite frustrating that *as soon as I push* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, a maximized window resizes to whichever size it had previously.  This happens across various applications.

---

**What is the name of this shortcut (not the particular accelerator that may be assigned)?  How do I disable this annoying behavior?**

Comment: Any ideas?  This is frustrating.